# Выяснить, на какой стороне улицы проживает больше жителей. Помогите пожалуйста с условием

Tags: java, arraylist, if, for, int

> Улицы и дома
>
> 1. Создать массив на 15 целых чисел.
> 2. Ввести в него значения с клавиатуры.
> 3. Пускай индекс элемента массива является номером дома, а значение - число жителей, проживающих в доме.
>
>    Дома с нечетными номерами расположены на одной стороне улицы, с четными - на другой. Выяснить, на какой стороне улицы проживает больше жителей.
> 4. Вывести на экран сообщение: "В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей." или "В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей."
>
> Примечание:
>
> дом с порядковым номером 0 считать четным.
>
> Требования:
>
> 1. Программа должна создавать массив на 15 целых чисел.
> 2. Программа должна считывать числа для массива с клавиатуры.
> 3. Программа должна вывести сообщение "В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей.", если сумма нечетных элементов массива больше суммы четных.
> 4. Программа должна вывести сообщение "В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей.", если сумма четных элементов массива больше суммы нечетных.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int[] num = new int[15];
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                even = even + i;
            } else if (i % 2 > 0)
            {
                odd = odd + i;
            } else {}
        }

        if (even > odd)
        {
            System.out.println("В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей.");
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей.");
        }
```

Comment: если считать в потоке, что в принципе правильно, то массив вообще не нужен. но т.к. условием является "Программа должна создавать массив на 15 целых чисел.", то, имхо, нужно разделить ввод массива и его последующую обработку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
        even = even + num[i];
      }
      else
      {
        odd = odd + num[i];
      }
```

И, возможно, нумерация домов все-таки начинается с единицы.